# Run Function from Button

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to figure out why this isn't working for the past half hour. Apologies if I'm being an idiot, but i just can't seem to make it work!

Javascript:

```
function cancel(){
alert("working");
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="cancel()" value="Cancel" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GaryP/Cg7yj/

Comment: try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/Cg7yj/2/

Comment: I don't know why this answer is downvoted. I agree, that it may seem strange at the first sight (because it should work), but Gary has just overseen the jsFiddle settings pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using JSFiddle, the "wrapping" options enclose your script in a function.

Functions defined in functions are only accessible to that particular function (like a variable declared with `var`), and therefore cannot be accessed by the button.

Choose one of the "no wrap" options.

Comment: Ah right, I was sure my code was correct! :/ Thanks for the help.